# xslt passing input document as String to java extension

Tags: xslt, binary

I am trying to write two XSL files, trying to achieve following goals:

1. It is supposed to encrypt the input document.
2. It is supposed to binary encode the XML document.

Example output of 1)

```
<Response>
  <encryptedData>e070dee5cb4688c608ee</encryptedData>
</Response>
```

Example output of 2)

```
<Response>
   <compressedData>ASCDee5cb4688c608ee</compressedData>
</Response>
```

For functionality #1, I have a Java extension function that takes a string input and returns an encrypted string. But I don't know how to pass the input document as string to the extension function.

For functionality #2, I am not sure how to convert input to binary XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XSLT cannot exactly reproduce the original string representing an XML document** -- due to various lexical peculiarities (and substitution of entity referencies) that are not able to reconstruct from the XmlDocument produced by the XML parser -- which is the input that an XSLT processor sees.

**You can pass to the extension function the document object (`/`)** and then the Java function can use a method like `OuterXml()` or `InnerXml()` to get one possible representation of the XML document.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give an answer to your first question on how to call a java function from an XSLT.
In your stylesheet declaration you have to define a namespace, e.g. `xmlns:filecounter="mappings.GenerateSequenceNumber"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:filecounter="mappings.GenerateSequenceNumber"
exclude-result-prefixes="filecounter" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```

In this case the java function is in the package "mappings" and the java class is called "GenerateSequenceNumber".

When calling the java function in your stylesheet you do for example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="filecounter:getSequenceNumber('countit',3)"/>
```

So you call the method "getSequenceNumber" in your java class and pass any variables that the java function needs in the brackets.

Unfortunately I can't help you with your second question.